# How to fetch the MIME type from byte array in Java 6?

Tags: java, arrays, mime-types

I have been trying to figure out how to fetch the *MIME type* from byte array in Java 6, but unfortunately have not been able fetch the MIME type yet.

Can someone help me get out of this?

Comment: byte[] contains a MIME Type? Please give more (much more!) details. And some source as example please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`MimetypesFileTypeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) provided class from Java 6. This class is exclusively used to fetch the *MIME type*.

Use it to fetch the MIME type as shown below:

```
byte[] content = ;
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```

For fetching from File you can use below code:

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mime = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
```

Comment: In mordern Java (11), you have to change `InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream` to `BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream` since `InputStream` has `.markSupported() == false` and hence `mimeType` is always null, whilst Buffered version has `.markSupported() == true``.

Comment: It comes as a standard but supports an abysmally small amount of mime types. For example, does not recognize PDFs. So not useful for general purpose computing.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Tika library](https://tika.apache.org/) is proving to be the most accurate in detecting proper MIME type from a byte array in my tests, much better than Java's `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()` which has proven not very reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Good working library https://github.com/overview/mime-types

Import (via gradle.kts):

```
implementation("org.overviewproject:mime-types:0.1.3")
```

Usage

```
// input
final var fileName = "somefile.html";
final var content = "<html></html>".getBytes();

final var mimeTypeDetector = new MimeTypeDetector(); // initialize only once, reuse!
final var mimeType = mimeTypeDetector.detectMimeType(fileName, () -> content);

System.out.println(mimeType); // prints: text/html
```

Comment: Code snippet makes use of java 10 features. Easy to downgrade!